# What is wrong in the next function of C++

Tags: c++, void

My goal is to accept 3 numbers, then sort them smallest to largest, I seem to have everything in order and good to go, but my print statement just prints the same thing twice, is it because I'm writing void wrong? here's what it looks like, if you need more of the code let me know:

```
int output1 = First;
int output2 = Second;
int output3 = Third;
void sort3(int output1,int output2,int output3); // Send to the sorting void.
```

the void:

```
void sort3(int &output1, int &output2, int &output3){
    void sort2(int output1, int output2);
    if (output1 > output3) {
        Swap(output1, output3);
    }
    if (output2 > output3) {
        Swap(output2, output3);
    }
    cout << output1 << "" << output2 << "" << output3 << "voided statement" << endl;
    return;
}

void sort2(int output1, int output2){
    if (output1 > output2)
        Swap(output1, output2);
    return;
}

void Swap(int &x, int &y) {
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
    return;
}
```

I was under the impression to send something you would just type the voids name and what youre sending in parenthesis,  but whenever I do that I get errors.

Comment: You keep using the word ‘void’ in very strange ways. Do you know what it means?

Comment: I can't understand your question. `void` as a return type just means a function that doesn't return something. You can't "send something to the void" and you can't "type the voids name". Do you mean "function"?!

Comment: `sort2` hasn't reference parameters, that's your "void error" *chuckle*

Comment: I suggest you read a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm) on how to use functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I see the problem. You are not calling a function here:

```
void sort3(int output1,int output2,int output3); // Send to the sorting void.
```

That *declares* the function `sort3`. It doesn't actually use the function. To use it you need to call it, like this:

```
sort3(output1, output2, output3);
```

Similarly, inside `sort3` you need to call `sort2` not just declare it:

```
sort2(output1, output2);
```

You also need to change `sort2` to take reference parameters, otherwise it just sorts its local variables, not the ones you pass to it. You got that right for `sort3` but not for `sort2`.

Comment: @vaxquis, it's certainly part of the problem, look at how he's trying to call the function. It doesn't matter if it has reference parameters or not if he never calls it.

Comment: Oh yes it is. (Ditto sort2)

Comment: @vaxquis, the missing reference parameters is a fairly simple mistake, and he'd already done it correctly for `sort3`. The root cause (ie. _the problem_) was the serious misunderstanding about how to call functions, not the easily-fixed function signature.

Comment: @JonathanWakely if he didn't understand how to call functions, I can safely say he doesn't understand function call argument semantics too, and wouldn't have fixed that other error by himself - I'm not arguing you found *a* problem - I'm just saying that *a problem* is not *the problem*; you completely fixed your answer, so I have completely no trouble with it, mate. OTOH, assuming an error trivial enough for a newbie to fix by himself is a risky endeavor...

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to change the `sort2` method to take values by reference for it to work, i.e. you'd have to change

```
void sort2(int output1, int output2)
```

to

```
void sort2(int &output1, int &output2)
```

2) You have to remove both return type (i.e. `void`) and variable type qualifiers (i.e. `int`) when you're trying to call the functions - otherwise you're declaring it, not calling it.